# Delete content staging websites

Tags: magento

How to delete content staging websites. I tried deleting the staging folder in the root but it's still showing up in admin panel but non-functional. Do you completely delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to "system -> Manage Stores" and delete your content websites there